# HYPERLINK not working with particular sheet names

Tags: excel, hyperlink, worksheet

I have a workbook - lets call it `Book1`

`Book1` contains 5 worksheets; `Sheet1`, `Sheet1A`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet2A`, `Summary`

Within the `Summary` worksheet there is a table which contains summary of the data held in the other 4 worksheet.

The first column in the table contains rows naming each of the 4 worksheets; `Sheet1`, `Sheet1A`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet2A`.

Using the excel `HYPERLINK` function I have created links in each of these rows so as to navigate directly to each particular worksheet, as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1", "Sheet1")
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1A!A1", "Sheet1A")
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2!A1", "Sheet2")
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2A!A1", "Sheet2A")
```

However, only two out of the four hyperlinks work. The two which do not work are those which end with 'A'; `Sheet1A` and `Sheet2A`

All worksheets have been spelt correctly and I have experiment with the format to see whether changing to text or general made any difference, but it did not.

Please could could someone shed some light on why I am facing an error with `Sheet1A` and `Sheet2A` - my thoughts are that it is something to do with there being a letter after the number?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're in the same workbook, then try adding the `#` & `'`

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&"Sheet1A'!A1", "Sheet1A")

=HYPERLINK("#'"&"Sheet2A'!A1", "Sheet2A")
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but adding # did not resolve the problem

Comment: That's odd, they only work for me _with_ the # (without it Excel tries to open a OneDrive URL in the browser). Which version of Excel are you using ?
Btw did you try the # in place of the filename?

Comment: Using Excel Microsoft 365. I tried # in place of filename; when using filename I get pop-up box comment stating 'Reference isnt valid' and when using # in place of filename I also get 'Reference isnt valid'

Comment: I'm also using 365 - given how you wrote "let's call it Book1", are the sheet names literally what you included in your post, or 'sample names' ?

Comment: They are sample names. The worksheets real names are P1251, P1251A, P5623, P5623A and the workbook is called 20220331_report .
Didn't realise that this would have any bearing

Comment: I've updated my sample with your actual names, and the # solution still works (P1251 and P5623 aren't good tab names as they are both valid cell addresses). Would you consider editing your post, just so that your 'actual syntax' can be seen?

Comment: @DiopChopra may be you need to add a single quote after `#` --> `=HYPERLINK("#'"&"Sheet1A'!A1", "Sheet1A")`

Comment: adding a single quote after `#` did the trick!! Thanks guys

Comment: @Mayukh actually provided the solution, so he should get the rep not me (although if a single quote resolved the issue then I think there must have been a single quote _already_ in the formula, which wasn't the case in what you posted)

Comment: Not a problem about rep. We are all sharing and learning here. So as long as it helps OP to resolve it ok. I just edited the Answer. with the one worked for OP